# Custom x-axis and y-axis range with Plotly heatmap

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Let's say we have a 2x4 matrix displayed into a Plotly.js `heatmap` (in reality it can be  500x1000):

```js
var data = [{z: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], type: 'heatmap'}];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {xaxis: { ticksuffix: " mm" }}, {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

How to change the x-axis to a custom range, and keep the plot full width?

For example `0 mm to 321 mm` (unit is millimiter), instead of `-0.5mm to 3.5mm` ?

PS: since the data can be big (500x1000 pixels), I'd like to avoid to have to insert `x, y` values in `data` itself, because it would make this object 3 times bigger (and the rendering is slow enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the x axis labels with a function.

Uncomment the `console.log()` statement if you want to see what values it's calculating.

```js
var zValues = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

var max = 321;
var multiplier = max / (zValues[0].length - 1);

var data = [{
  z: zValues
  , type: 'heatmap'
  , x: zValues[0].map(function(el, idx) { /* console.log(idx, idx * multiplier); */ return idx * multiplier; }),
}];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {xaxis: { ticksuffix: " mm" }}, {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If you don't want the first point at 0 (sending the first x axis mark negative) then you can change the formula to

```js
var zValues = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

var max = 321;
var multiplier = max / (zValues[0].length);

var data = [{
  z: zValues
  , type: 'heatmap'
  , x: zValues[0].map(function(el, idx) { /* console.log(idx, idx * multiplier + multiplier); */ return idx * multiplier + multiplier; }),
}];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {xaxis: { ticksuffix: " mm" }}, {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Since you're using `zValues[0]`, the length of `x` will be the length of only one row of `z`. Does Plotly understand if `z` is of shape 100x100 and `x` of shape only 100?

Comment: Should do. I'm using the count of the items in the first inner array for that reason (`[1, 2, 3, 4]`). In your case with a 100 by 100 matrix that should be a count of 100. Your example is a 4 x 2 and my code spreads the 4 X-values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the range property of the xaxis object. This property takes an array of two values, representing the minimum and maximum values for the x-axis.

```js
var data = [{z: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], type: 'heatmap'}];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    range: [0, 321],
    ticksuffix: " mm"
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I converted your answer into runnable snippet. Unfortunately, `range` doesn't work, see example: the plot doesn't use full width from left to right.

Comment: @Basj Given the data is clustered at one end, why would the plot cover the full width when displaying a range from 0 to 321?

Comment: @KScandrett The range `[0, 3]` should be rescaled to `[0, 321]`.