# Heatmap and image layers on top of each other with Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

With Plotly.JS I have:

- `z0` a 500 x 200 array, to be displayed as `'heatmap'`, with axis in millimeters in range 0 .. 2500mm x 0 .. 1000mm   (thus the x, y axis are *rescaled* with a factor `multiplier = 5.0`), here this trace is rendered as a constant grey color because the value is constant
- `z1` an RGB array of size 2000 x 800 (x3 for RGB), to be displayed with `type: 'image'`, *exactly on top* of `z0`: both layers should be on top of each other (here it can work because same aspect ratio)

The following code works, but unfortunately, `z1` doesn't take the full width / full height.

How to modify the following code such that the RGB image `z1` takes the full width / full height, i.e. up to 2500mm and 1000mm for x, y axis ?

```js
var multiplier = 5.0;
var z0 = Array.from({length: 200}, () => Array.from({length: 500}, () => 100));
var z1 = Array.from({length: 800}, () => Array.from({length: 2000}, () => [Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255]));
var x_values = z0[0].map((el, idx) => idx * multiplier);
var y_values = z0.map((el, idx) => (z0.length - idx - 1) * multiplier);
const data = [
  {type: 'image', z: z1, colormodel: 'rgb', x: x_values, y: y_values},
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z0, colorscale: 'Cividis', opacity: 0.6, x: x_values, y: y_values }
];
const layout = {width: 600, xaxis: {anchor: 'y', scaleanchor: 'y', constrain: 'domain', "ticksuffix": " mm"}, yaxis: {anchor: 'x', autorange: 'reversed', constrain: 'domain', "ticksuffix": " mm"}};
Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Linked questions:

- [Custom x-axis and y-axis range with Plotly heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74991116/custom-x-axis-and-y-axis-range-with-plotly-heatmap/75076214#75076214)
- [Two heatmaps on top of each other with opacity with Plotly.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359950/two-heatmaps-on-top-of-each-other-with-opacity-with-plotly-js)

Note:

I tried to create other `x: x_values_2, y: y_values_2` arrays for the trace `z1`, with another multiplier, but it seems it has no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure you can set `x` and `y` for the image trace as you do for the heatmap. Though, having the heatmap rescaled to 1000*2500, the 800*2000 image would need a scale factor of 1.25, which you can set with `dx: 1.25, dy: 1.25`. is it what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Also note that the code currently places z0 on top of z1, not the contrary (according to the trace order in the data array).

Comment: +100 @EricLavault! You can post your comment as an answer, thanks one million times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't set `x` and `y` for the image trace as we do for the heatmap.

Though, having the heatmap rescaled to 1000x2500, an 800*2000 image would need a scale factor of 1.25 to match, which we can set using [`dx` and `dy`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/image/#image-dx) :

```js
const data = [
  {type: 'image', z: z1, colormodel: 'rgb', dx: 1.25, dy: 1.25},
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z0, colorscale: 'Cividis', opacity: 0.6, x: x_values, y: y_values }
];
```

Also note that the code currently places z0 on top of z1, not the contrary (according to the trace order in the data array).